# Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server-Edition

Tags: jakarta-ee, ubuntu-12.04, glassfish-3, ubuntu-10.04, glassfish-4

I unzipped Glassfish-Server 3.1.2.2 as usual and called "./asadmin start-domain" to start the server and the admin web-interface. This always worked with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. Now I tried the same procedure with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS... The login window shows up correctly, after entering username and password, I am redirected to a white page.

Does someone know why? How to solve? Any logs that I could check?

EDIT: besides "Certificate has expired" only the following entry is in the log file:

```
[#|2014-03-11T10:34:56.309+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=131;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Redirecting to /index.jsf|#]
```

The "Certificate has expired" message occurs also on my other GF3+ installations on Ubuntu 10.04 where everything works just fine...

Is there a potential "new" security feature in Ubuntu 12.04 (compared to 10.04) that prevents the admin-web-gui from being loaded due to the "Certificate has expired" message ?

Comment: Try looking at `<glassfish-home>/glassfish/domains/<your-domain>/logs/server.log` and check for any errors.

Comment: I added the log-entry in the original message (as EDIT). There's no further message indicating why the web-interface should not work.

Comment: Did you enable the admin interface with `asadmin enable-secure-admin`?

Comment: Yes I did... without it's not possible to access over the network.

Comment: You can try to increase logs to INFO level and check if you find more information.